# Why my vmware shows two partition for same disk space?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem

While I was watching a tutorial I noticed he only had one partition but I have two. And can I change my File system partition from FAT to Linux.

```
Can anyone make me understand this picture.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a 33GB disk. There are two partitions and about 1GB of unallocated space. The largest partition is a logical partition inside an extended partition. You have MBR partitioning. I explained what this is here [What is extended file system and how to merge it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334561/what-is-extended-file-system-and-how-to-merge-it/1334572#1334572)

The small FAT partition will be critical to the boot process. If you were to change it to a Linux filesystem it would not boot.

Comment: yes  I just expanded the disk size minutes before posting this.